# I can't position to a specific page of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, paging

I am using a jqgrid but am having trouble positioning to a specific page. I have seen a couple of examples using reloadGrid which I have tried but it doesn't work. I have a large data set that is paged. If I try to go to page 76 of my data set it acts like it is trying to do it as the "View" count at the bottom is correct however the grid is displayed empty (even though my JSON data looks correct). I notice the scroll bar is still positioned to the top and if I touch it it automatically reloads back to page 1. Am I missing something?

Here is my grid definition:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid({
  url: 'jqgrid.php?cmd=getrecs',
  editurl: 'jqgrid.php?cmd=editrec',
  datatype: 'json',
  colNames:['Branch', 'Description', 'Type', 'Active' ],
  colModel :[
    {name:'rbranch',
            index:'rbranch',
            sortable:true,
            editable:true
    },
    {name:'des',
            index:'des',
            sortable:true,
            editable:true
    },
    {name:'type',
            index:'type',
            sortable:true,
            editable:true
    },
    {name:'status',
            index:'status',
            sortable:false,
            editable:true
    }
  ],
  pager: '#pager1',
  sortname: 'rbranch',
  sortorder: 'asc',
  rowNum: 100, // Only fetch 100 at a time
  viewrecords: true,
  scroll: 1,
  sortable: true,
  caption: 'Scheduling Resources'
});

$("#list1).navGrid("#pager1",
  // Turn on the icons
  {edit:true,
          add:true,
          del:true,
          search:true,
          refresh:true,
          refreshstate:'current',
          view:true
  },
  // Edit dialog parameters
  {reloadAfterSubmit: false,
          closeAfterEdit: true
  },
  // Add dialog parameters
  {reloadAfterSubmit: true,
          closeAfterAdd: true
  },
  // Delete dialog parameters
  {reloadAfterSubmit: false},
  // Search dialog parameters
  {},
  // View dialog parameters
  {}
);
```

To go to page 76 I am trying this:

```
$("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:76}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `scroll: 1` option. It's a special virtual scrolling mode. In the mode many things work in another way or not works at all. You can try to remove the option and use standard paging.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I got it working but that is a bummer about the scrolling. I like that behavior much better than the paging model.

Comment: @ToddR: You are welcome! The problem is that virtual scrolling can be implemented only with many tricks. I find the current implementation in jqGrid not safe. So it's probably one feature which I don't recommend to use. The usage of other form of pager is just the matter of habit. If you come from fat-client you like virtual scrolling, but one can work with the standard paging also very good. It's really typical way for web applications.

Comment: I understand. I will have to get used to it. The main reason I didn't like the regular paging is that you still have to use the scroll bar. So it is like you are paging AND still scrolling at the same time. I thought you might as well just use the scroll bar by itself. Anyway, thanks for the help! It is working much better.

Comment: @ToddR: If you use `height: 'auto'` (used in almost all my examples on the stackoverflow) you will have no vertical scrolling bar.